# Project templates are overwritten when opened from recent projects

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, template

I created various project templates in QGIS. They do work as intended initially, as you can load them from the starting screen. As soon as you change anything after opening the template, you cannot save it anymore under the same name (which I think is intended and makes sense).
However, after you opened the template once, the original project gets listed as recent project and any changes made will automatically overwrite the template when saving the project. How do I solve this issue? Is the easiest way just to tell my colleagues not to open from recent projects?

Comment: I'm not by my computer so I can't check exactly where, but somewhere in the settings you can choose not to display recent projects when starting up QGIS. Would that help?

Comment: Not really, since we obviously work on projects that should be listed. Just the template should never be shown as a project, only as template